# Imbeding code into the pixels of an image file

Tags: windows, firefox

1.)Is there a way to embed code into an image file?

2.)If, and most likely is very possible, ...Then which Image file type would be best suited for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes you can embed any digital data, like a virus, data, etc. into an image file.  However, *executing* that code is a far more difficult task.  Image files arent executed like a program, they are simply read by another program.

If the image viewing program was poorly written, it is conceivable a security flaw, such as a buffer overrun, could allow code to be executed.  Finding such a vulnerability, if it is even there, is way beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming you mean "a code" as in a hidden message, then you are probably thinking of [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), which is the concealment of a message using elements of an image (e.g. pixels embedded in the image in a certain pattern can be translated by someone who knows the schema into a message, often encoded). One recent newsworthy example is colour laser printers, some of which include small, faint coloured dots in the background of printed pages, which allow information about the printer, document, and even the user who printed it to be determined later on by looking at the printed paper, even though it is not readily visible to the naked eye. On the other hand, if you mean "computer code", then image formats are not typically designed to contain logic.
2. A lossless image format (e.g. most PNG or BMP), which is designed to preserve all information in the image whenever it is saved, would be more suitable than a lossy image format, which could change when resaved (e.g. JPEG).